# Recursive CTE- Gives me dupes of 3 rows

Tags: common-table-expression, recursive-cte

I am trying to find a group account and populate the aggregation of its child accounts QTY and Market value using CTE and Recursive CTE.. it gives me the correct result 3 times.. Not sure what i am missing here.

Scenario:
Example
Composite account CMP_1 contains the following account memberships.
DIM_ACCOUNT_CONSTITUENT
PARENT_ACCT_CD  CHILD_ACCT_CD
CMP_1   FND_A
CMP_1   FND_B
CMP_1   FND_C
The holding for each account asof 11/13/2022 for all sources of data is shown below.
FCT_POSITION_SECURITY_LEVEL
SERVICE_ID  POSITION_DATE   ACCT_CD SEC_ID  LONG_SHT_CD STRATEGY_ID QTY
1111    11/13/2022  FND_A   101 L   ~NA~    1000
1111    11/13/2022  FND_A   201 S   ~NA~    2000
1111    11/13/2022  FND_A   301 L   ~NA~    3000
1111    11/13/2022  FND_B   201 L   ~NA~    2000
1111    11/13/2022  FND_B   301 L   ~NA~    3000
1111    11/13/2022  FND_C   101 L   ~NA~    1000
1111    11/13/2022  FND_D   401 S   ~NA~    4000
2222    11/13/2022  FND_A   401 L   ~NA~    4000
2222    11/13/2022  FND_A   501 S   ~NA~    5000
2222    11/13/2022  FND_A   601 L   ~NA~    6000
2222    11/13/2022  FND_C   401 L   ~NA~    4000
2222    11/13/2022  FND_D   501 S   ~NA~    5000
When aggregation is applied, the following new data is created for the composite account. Notice the aggregation is based on the position business key POSITION_ID which is POSITION_DATE, ACCT_CD, SEC_ID, LONG_SHT_CD, and STRATEGY_ID. Not shown in this example is aggregation across any FCT_POSITION_SECURITY_LEVEL extension (_EXT) tables. Aggregation would work in the same way.
SERVICE_ID  POSITION_DATE   ACCT_CD SEC_ID  LONG_SHT_CD STRATEGY_ID QTY
1111    11/13/2022  CMP_1   101 L   ~NA~    2000
1111    11/13/2022  CMP_1   201 L   ~NA~    2000
1111    11/13/2022  CMP_1   201 S   ~NA~    2000
1111    11/13/2022  CMP_1   301 L   ~NA~    6000
1111    11/13/2022  CMP_1   401 S   ~NA~    4000
2222    11/13/2022  CMP_1   401 L   ~NA~    8000
2222    11/13/2022  CMP_1   501 S   ~NA~    10000
2222    11/13/2022  CMP_1   601 L   ~NA~    6000

Query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
PS.SERVICE_ID,
PS.POSITION_DATE,
PARENT_ACCT_CD AS ACCT_CD,
PS.SEC_ID,
PS.LONG_SHT_CD,
PS.STRATEGY_ID,
PS.QTY,
PS.MKT_VAL
FROM
DIM_ACCOUNT_CONSTITUENT AC
INNER JOIN
FCT_POSITION_SECURITY_LEVEL PS
ON
AC.CHILD_ACCT_CD = PS.ACCT_CD
WHERE
AC.PARENT_ACCT_CD = 'CMP_1' AND
PS.POSITION_DATE =CURRENT_DATE()
),
REC_CTE AS (
SELECT
SERVICE_ID,
POSITION_DATE,
ACCT_CD,
SEC_ID,
LONG_SHT_CD,
STRATEGY_ID,
QTY,
MKT_VAL
FROM
CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT
CTE.SERVICE_ID,
CTE.POSITION_DATE,
DIM_ACCOUNT_CONSTITUENT.PARENT_ACCT_CD AS ACCT_CD,
CTE.SEC_ID,
CTE.LONG_SHT_CD,
CTE.STRATEGY_ID,
CTE.QTY,
CTE.MKT_VAL
FROM
CTE
INNER JOIN
DIM_ACCOUNT_CONSTITUENT
ON
CTE.ACCT_CD = DIM_ACCOUNT_CONSTITUENT.CHILD_ACCT_CD
WHERE
DIM_ACCOUNT_CONSTITUENT.PARENT_ACCT_CD <> 'CMP_1'
AND CTE.POSITION_DATE=current_date()
)
SELECT *
FROM REC_CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue, in my query, I have a Dimension table with precursory rows. adding a "where" clause filter would fix it.